# Why does table paragraph ending-symbol has length 2?

Tags: vba, ms-word

If you run the code below you will find something really confusing: "table paragraphs" end with ending-paragraph symbol with one character (ASCII code 13), but with length equal 2.

Why that happen?

**Active Document**

[image]

**Code**

```
Sub Detect_Table_And_Conventinal_Paragraphs()
    Dim para
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If para.Range.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "table para", "Len:", Len(para.Range.Text), "Asc:", Asc(para.Range.Characters(1)), para.Range.Characters.Count
        Else
            Debug.Print "conve para", "Len:", Len(para.Range.Text), "Asc:", Asc(para.Range.Characters(1))
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

**Immediate Window**

```
table para    Len:           2            Asc:           13            1 
table para    Len:           2            Asc:           13            1 
conve para    Len:           1            Asc:           13
```

Comment: You can check the binary contents of the string using the [StringToHex](https://github.com/guwidoe/VBA-StringTools/blob/6a941b54a8027c975875446b1bde90648e833ddb/src/LibStringTools.bas#LL984C1-L984C1) function from my repository. There are also many other tools available in the repo that you might find helpful to deal with such issues, unfortunately it's still an early version and not much documentation is available apart from comments above the function declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is confusing. Probably only the authors of Word know "why". But...

Each table cell has an end-of-cell character (ASCII 7).

When you get the text of the range of the last paragraph in a cell, the last character of the text is ascii 7), so e.g. if para 4 in the document is such a paragraph, then

Asc(Right(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(4).Range.Text,1))

would return 7. But

ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(4).Range.Characters *does not* include the end-of-cell marker.

Incidentally, when dealing with Ranges you sometimes have to use the TextRetrievalMode member of the Word Range object to count the characters correctly, e.g. you can use that object to tell word whether to count hidden characters or not count them. But I don't think any of the settings in there change the way that end-of-cell markers are treated.

Comment: Many thanks. The info you gave us is exactly what I was looking for. From what I got, the last paragraph of each cell table have a range text string whose last two positions equals Chr(13) & Chr(7), and each row table have a paragraph whose range text string equals Chr(13) & Chr(7).